# I think I fork-bombed my server with a cron job - what's happening here and how do I recover?

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I scheduled a simple python script to run every minute under the user `foo`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/home/foo/.bash_profile

* * * * * python /home/foo/slack-bot/main.py 2>&1 /home/foo/slack-bot.log
```

After a few mins I got these errors and was soon after kicked off my server

```
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: wait_for: No record of process 32012
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
-bash: wait_for: No record of process 32012
....
```

Uh oh. So I tried logging in as `root` and sudo-ing as `foo`

```
sudo -iu foo
sudo: unable to execute /bin/bash: Cannot allocate memory
```

Great.

I then removed the offending line from the `foo` user's crontab file, and also killed all processes with `slack` in the name

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'slack' | awk '{print $2}')
```

I now get a different error, but I still can't sudo that user:

```
sudo -iu foo
-bash: xmalloc: .././copy_cmd.c:86: cannot allocate 32 bytes (450560 bytes allocated)
```

What's going on here? I'm sure there's an error in my cron schedule which I'll investigate, but what kind of behavior causes the out of memory fork errors? What's the best way to recover besides a hard-reset?

Thanks!

Comment: A simple `sudo reboot` should fix it, I think

Comment: thanks. I did a reset and it's cleared, but I'm trying to understand a bit more about what these errors mean. How are they raised, and are there ways to recover without resetting?

Answer (score 1):

Its a common launch pattern - depends on what you need ... you may

- increase time between process launch to increase likelihood prior has finished
- identify if prior launch is still running if so terminate
- create a long running daemon instead of a short running process
- launch - do work then terminate - have a watcher process spin up new launch only when it discovers its not running ( a la supervisord )

without knowing the use case its hard to proceed